# How do you set up jOOQ audit columns in the gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, jooq, jooq-codegen

Trying to write a small demo app to check that [jOOQ's audit columns](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.17/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-audit/) are doing what we are expecting them to.

Just have a`last_modified` timestamptz and a `last_modifier` integer ID

With the info on that linked page above, I would expect that to look something like:

build.gradle.kts (`jooq-codegen`)

```kotlin
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.ForcedType
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging

plugins {
    id("nu.studer.jooq") version "7.1.1"
}

val jooqGroup by extra{"org.jooq.trial-java-8"}
val jooqVersion by extra{"3.17.3"}

dependencies {
    api("$jooqGroup:jooq:$jooqVersion")
    implementation("$jooqGroup:jooq-codegen:$jooqVersion")
    implementation("$jooqGroup:jooq-meta:$jooqVersion")
    jooqGenerator("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.4.2")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.4.2")
}

jooq {
    version.set(jooqVersion)
    edition.set(nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.TRIAL_JAVA_8)

    configurations {
        create("poc") {
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation.set(false)

            jooqConfiguration.apply {
                logging = Logging.WARN
                jdbc.apply {
                    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
                    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydemo"
                    user = "foo"
                    password = "bar"
                }
                generator.apply {
                    name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator"
                    database.apply {
                        name = "org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase"
                        inputSchema = "public"
                        forcedTypes.addAll(listOf(
                            ForcedType().apply {
                                name = "varchar"
                                includeExpression = ".*"
                                includeTypes = "JSONB?"
                            },
                            ForcedType().apply {
                                name = "varchar"
                                includeExpression = ".*"
                                includeTypes = "INET"
                            },
                            ForcedType().apply {
                                auditUpdateUser = true
                                name = "int"
                                includeExpression = "last_modifier"
                            },
                            ForcedType().apply {
                                auditUpdateTimestamp = true
                                name = "timestamptz"
                                includeExpression = "last_modified"
                            }
                        ))
                    }
                    generate.apply {
                        isPojos = false
                        isDaos = false
                        isRecords = true
                        isDeprecated = false
                    }
                    target.apply {
                        packageName = "my.app.jooq"
                        directory = "src/main/java"
                    }
                    strategy.name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

except both `auditUpdateUser` and `auditUpdateTimestamp` are an

> Unresolved reference

I suspect reason for that is that audit columns seem to be only available starting from jOOQ `3.17` and [studer's latest plugin version](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/releases) is lagging behind by supporting only up to `3.16.4`.

Given this - and assuming that is indeed correct - how do I best enable the audit columns?

I could of course try to subclass `ForcedType` and see if I can add support for it there until the plugin officially supports it.

But is there an easier way to set up audit columns without having to do that?

**UPDATE**

So the problem is that `org.jooq.meta.jaxb.ForcedType` imported at the top is of version `3.16.4` instead of `3.17.3`.

we can enforce the correct version, as Lukas mentioned in his answer below, by adding

```
buildscript {
    configurations["classpath"].resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.jooq") {
            useVersion("3.17.3")
        }
    }
}
```

to the beginning of the script.

However, this seems to pull in the open-source version of jOOQ which requires java 17 (and the target project is still on java 11).

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jooq/meta/jaxb/Configuration has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

I do not think we should need to update to java 17 to use a dependency that is java-8 compatible.

https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/183 suggests something like

```
dependencies {
    api("$jooqGroup:jooq:$jooqVersion")
    implementation("$jooqGroup:jooq-codegen:$jooqVersion")
    implementation("$jooqGroup:jooq-meta:$jooqVersion")
    jooqGenerator("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.4.2")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.4.2")

    modules {
        module("org.jooq:jooq") {
            replacedBy("$jooqGroup:jooq", "nu.studer.jooq bugfix #183") // https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/183
        }
    }
}
```

may help, but so far hasn't had any noticeable effect.

**UPDATE**

For reproductability, the `build.gradle.kts (jooq-codegen)` project is part of a small spring application that has two modules: `jooq-codegen` and `server`. Here are the other two gradle files:

build.gradle.kts(`app`)

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.13.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}

springBoot {
    mainClass.value("my.app.server.JooqAuditLoggingApplication")
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal{
            content{
                includeGroup("org.jooq.trial-java-8")
            }
        }
    }
    group = "my.app"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

    tasks.withType<JavaCompile>{
        options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin ="io.spring.dependency-management")
    apply(plugin ="java-library")

    java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

project("jooq-codegen"){
}

project("server"){
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    apply(plugin ="org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring")

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "17"
        }
    }

    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts(`server`)

```kotlin
import org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.3"
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "9.0.1"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":jooq-codegen"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq"){
        exclude("org.jooq","jooq")
    }
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
}

flyway {*emphasized text*
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydemo"
    user = "foo"
    password = "bar"
    schemas = arrayOf("public")
    locations = arrayOf("classpath:db/migration")
    ignoreMigrationPatterns = arrayOf("*:missing")
    cleanDisabled = false
}
tasks.withType<FlywayMigrateTask>{
    dependsOn("processResources")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the readme of the plugin, section [*"Enforcing the jOOQ configuration XML schema version"*](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin#enforcing-the-jooq-configuration-xml-schema-version), this should work?

```kotlin
buildscript {
    configurations["classpath"].resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.jooq-trial-java-8") {
            useVersion("3.17.3")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm ... that seems to be incompatible with Java 11 because it was compiled with Java 17 (`UnsupportedClassVersionError`)?

Comment: @User1291: I guess it should be `requested.group == "org.jooq.trial-java-8"`, instead? Can you try that? I'll update my answer if that works

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: OK, then, I don't know. Sorry. Perhaps ask the maintainer: https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues