# How do you provide client-side audit information to jOOQ?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jooq

I'm not entirely sure how to populate the [Audit Columns](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.17/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-audit/) I specify in my project.

I configured a integer-type user id as my "user" column:

```kotlin
ForcedType().apply {
    isAuditUpdateUser = true
    name = "int"
    includeExpression = "last_modifier"
},
ForcedType().apply {
    isAuditUpdateTimestamp = true
    name = "timestamptz"
    includeExpression = "last_modified"
}
```

To quote the documentation:

> All such audit columns compute their actual value from Configuration.auditProvider(), which allows for overriding the org.jooq.impl.DefaultAuditProvider behaviour

So I was expecting to be able to declare a configuration like this in the `server` module:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class JooqConfig(
    private val principalService: PrincipalService, //has access to spring security context
) {
    @Bean
    fun configurationCustomizer() = DefaultConfigurationCustomizer { c: DefaultConfiguration ->
        c.setAuditProvider(auditProvider())
    }

    @Bean
    fun auditProvider(): AuditProvider = PrincipalAwareAuditProvider(principalService)

    private class PrincipalAwareAuditProvider(private val principalService: PrincipalService) : DefaultAuditProvider(){

        override fun <T : Any?> provideUser(ctx: GeneratorContext<*, *, T>): Field<T>? {
            val userId = principalService.currentUserId()
            return ctx.field()?.let { field ->
                when(field.dataType.type){
                    Int::class.java -> TODO("do something with userId")
                    else -> null
                }
            }
        }

        override fun <T : Any?> provideTimestamp(ctx: GeneratorContext<*, *, T>?): Field<T>? {
            TODO("figure out what to do about this")
        }

    }
}
```

BUT I'm not sure how or why to create a `Field` out of the `userId`.
Am I trying to do this in the wrong place?

How do I fill the audit columns with values?

Comment: Before I try to answer, have you been able to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/73522248/521799, if so, would you mind providing an answer, there? I'm asking because *"this provideUser function doesn't seem to actually get called when I execute an update query"*. Does your code generation configuration have any effect on the generated code?

Comment: *"the provideUser's returning a Field kind of got me stumped"* - Can you be specific about what your question is, here?

Comment: Ad 1: "Yes", I just upgraded to java 17. That's an ok workaround but I kept the isue open because there may be a nicer solution, somewhere down the road. And yes, it does have an effect ... yes, I can see e.g. `public final TableField<StuffRecord, Integer> LAST_MODIFIER = createField(DSL.name("last_modifier"), SQLDataType.INTEGER.nullable(false).stored().defaultValue(DSL.field("0", SQLDataType.INTEGER)), this, "", new org.jooq.impl.AuditGenerator<>(org.jooq.AuditType.TIMESTAMP, org.jooq.GeneratorStatementType.UPDATE));` being added to the generated table object.

Comment: Ad 2: Well, I am expecting to provide an integer. It's not entirely clear why or how to make a `Field` out of it and that makes me think I may be trying to provide the value for the audit columns in the wrong place.

Comment: AND thanks to you I just noticed that I added `isAuditUpdateTimestamp` instead of `isAuditUpdateUser` for the user column. Thank you. the method now gets called, but I still have no idea how to turn the value into a `Field` instance.

Comment: significantly simplified the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of returning a `Field<T>` (an *expression*) rather than just the value `T` (a client side *value*) is, well, to allow for creating expressions.

Imagine you're using e.g. Oracle's `SYS_CONTEXT` to populate contextual values like that directly from within the database. How could you possibly access `SYS_CONTEXT` expressions if this SPI didn't allow you to provide a `Field<T>`?

If your value is purely client side generated, then just [wrap it in a bind value, explicitly](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/). But a bind value is just a special case of the more generic case where you produce server side *expressions*.

Comment: Can you be more explicit in *how* to "wrap it in a bind value, explicitly"? All the examples in the documentation you linked have access to the `Query` object,  I don't have that, I have a `GeneratorContext` and bit of a confusion. `field.binding = Binding.of( ??? )` sounds like too complicated an interface to be expected in this situtation, for example.

Comment: Looks like an unchecked cast is the way to go. `DSL.val(userId) as Field<T>` seems to do the trick. Not sure if there's a nicer way to do it.

Comment: @User1291 Yeah, in most cases, you need unchecked casts. I don't understand your question about the *how*. Perhaps, ask a new *specific* question?